# I would like to add a behavior just before the forced termination

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cmd

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class ScheduleService implements CommandLineRunner, ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent>, DisposableBean {
  @Override
    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        try {
            System.out.println("exit");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

There is no problem when closing the project in IntelliJ to run the method in the Spring Boot project.

However, if the project is built into a jar file and then executed in the cmd window and then forced to close, the method does not work.

Is there a way to execute the destroy() function even if I force quit by clicking the "X" button of cmd? If you exit normally with ctrl+c, there is no problem, but users click the "X" button in cmd.

Comment: Try (better experiment): log to file ... Or pipe/redirect output (`>` in cmd.exe)

Comment: And even if it behaves differently, where should it print??(what is "system.out", when user "closes cmd" (shell/window)??;)

Comment: The output should be from the shell

Answer (score 1):

use:

log.info("exit")

and try to find it in **application.log**